# How can I use ObjectArray to useEffect's second argument

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use `useEffect` even if one small element of the object changes.

Like this

```
useEffect(()=>{do Something},[some ObjectArray])
```

I know that Object and Array just points to a specific address value.

So worried that React will recognize that the contents of `useEffect`'s second argument have not changed even if the value of the object changes.

I tried

```
useEffect(()=>{do Something},[JSON.stringfy(Object)]);
```

I am not sure if the method I am trying to use is effective.

And also key property also uses `JSON.stringify`, but I don't know if I can put this long string in the key value.

Like this

```
<SomeComponent 
 key={Json.stringFy(someObject)}]
/>
```

Whenever the contents of an object that comes in from outside change.
hope state of the component is change.

** Thank you for many answers. So I knew exactly what to do. The exact question is whether the object has changed, not whether it triggers useEffect. thank you guys! **

Comment: Where is you object, in state or props?

Comment: can you recreate object instead of mutating it? so it would be referentially different.

Comment: @skyboyer  yes i can but I want to do useEffect when Object Array change ...! Thanks to you, I came up with an idea. check the object has changed first, if it has changed, then we can create a new one.

Comment: How do you determine which object to subscribe to? I'm assuming this object would come via props.

Comment: @Christopher Ngo 4 sorry i am not good at En but i guess you mean why i don't use the object to just a prop right?

Comment: @ravibagul91  prop it came from prop

Comment: Are you using something like redux that updates the array of objects? It almost feels like we're trying to solve a problem that already solves itself :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not stringify it because that will be an expensive comparison on every render. It will check every character and that can be difficult for large arrays. You should only update the array immutable by using [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) or [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer). This will easily let you modify an object within the array and return a new, changed array, which will trigger a new useEffect . This will not only benefit your hooks but also improve performance if you use a pure component or memo for functional components.